# How to get a default generic delegate for a type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic delegate like this:

```
public delegate T SomeHandler<T>(T input);
```

I have a generic class that take the delegate as a parameter to its constructor like this:

```
public class SomeClass<T>
{
  private SomeHandler<T> m_handler;

  public SomeClass(SomeHandler<T> handler)
  {
    m_handler = handler;
  }

  public void DoSomeStuff(T input)
  {
     T result = m_handler(input);
     // some stuff
  }
}
```

Most of the time I would instantiate the class with a default handler unless some special case is needed. So I have some default handlers for the types I use:

```
public static class DefaultHandlers
{
  public static string DefaultStringHandler(string input)
  {
    return input;
  }
}
```

In some cases, the type is instantiated with a special handler that is specific to its implementation:

```
public class Example
{
  private SomeClass<string> m_typicalCase;

  private SomeClass<string> m_specialCase;

  public Example()
  {
    m_typicalCase = new SomeClass<string>(DefaultHandlers.DefaultStringHandler);
    m_specialCase = new SomeClass<string>(SpecialHandler);
  }

  private string SpecialHandler(string input)
  {
    string result;
    // Do something special
    return result;
  }
}
```

I want to create a default constructor for **SomeClass** that always instantiates the class with the same default handler for that type, but since the type is not know at compile time, I can't return the delegate that is the right type.

```
public class SomeClass<T>
{

  ...

  public SomeClass()
  {
    m_handler = DefaultHandlers.GetDefaultHandler<T>();
  }

  ...

}
```

Like this

```
public static class DefaultHandlers
{
  public static SomeHandler<T> GetDefaultHandler<T>()
  {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
    {
      return DefaultStringHandler;
    }
  }
}
```

This does not work becuase **DefaultStringHandler** returns a *string* and the method expects *T*.

The only way that I have found to do this is the make a type-specific subclass of **SomeClass** that overloads the default constructor:

```
public class SomeStringClass : SomeClass<string>
{

  public SomeStringClass()
  : base(DefaultHandlers.DefaultStringHandler)
  {
  }

  public SomeStringClass(SomeHandler<string> handler)
  : base(handler)
  {
  }

}
```

It would be fun if generic types could have type-specific overloaded constructors that are used when instantiating the class of a specific type:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
  public Foo<string>(string input)
  {
  }

  public Foo<int>(int input)
  {
  }

  public Foo(T input)
  {
  }
}
```

There must be a more elegant way to do with with a design pattern, Strategy maybe?

Comment: Well what do you want the default handler to do for *other* types? If it's always just "return the input value" then that's easy.

Comment: `(SomeHandler<T>)DefaultStringHandler` should work... (Also as Jon Skeet pointed out if it is always identity you can simply inline it using lambda for example: `x => x`)

Comment: I don't think my example for the handler that takes the input and returns the same type is quite realistic. In reality, there are a number of handlers that either take the type T as input and output something else, or they take some other type and output T. Somewhat like a type converter. I would want the default behavior to be different depending on the type of T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize `dynamic` to get something like `SomeClass<string>()`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Zoltan
{

    public class SomeClass<T>
    {
        private static readonly Func<T,T> FALL_BACK_HANDLER = a => a; //or what have you

        private readonly Func<T,T> m_handler;

        public SomeClass(Func<T,T> handler)
        {
            m_handler = handler;
        }

        public SomeClass()
        {
            m_handler = DefaultHandler.For<T>() ?? FALL_BACK_HANDLER;
        }

        public void DoSomeStuff(T input)
        {
            T result = m_handler(input);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }

    public static class DefaultHandler
    {
        public static Func<T,T> For<T>()
        {
            return TypeAware<T>.Default;
        }

        private static class TypeAware<T>
        {
            private static readonly Func<T,T> DEFAULT;
            static TypeAware()
            {
                var type = typeof(T);
                if (type == typeof(string))
                {
                    DEFAULT = a => DefaultHandler.StringHandler((dynamic) a);
                }
                else if (type == typeof(int))
                {
                    DEFAULT = a => DefaultHandler.IntHandler((dynamic) a);
                }
                else
                {
                    DEFAULT = null;
                }
            }

            public static Func<T,T> Default { get { return DEFAULT; } }
        }

        public static string StringHandler(string a)
        {
            return a + " The default handler does some stuff!";
        }

        public static int IntHandler(int a)
        {
            return a + 2;
        }
    }
}
```

You would then consume `SomeClass` as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Zoltan
{    
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var someStringObj = new SomeClass<string>();
            someStringObj.DoSomeStuff("Hello World.");//prints "Hello World. The default handler does some stuff!"

            var someIntObj = new SomeClass<int>();
            someIntObj.DoSomeStuff(1);//prints 3

            var someCustomDoubleObj = new SomeClass<double>(d => d - 2);
            someCustomDoubleObj.DoSomeStuff(3);//prints 1

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Jon Skeet and Alexei Levenkovs comments. From what I understand, something like this might be what you're after?

```
public delegate T SomeHandler<T>(T input);

public class SomeClass<T>
{
    private SomeHandler<T> m_handler;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        m_handler = (T input) => input;
    }

    public SomeClass(SomeHandler<T> handler)
    {
        m_handler = handler;
    }

    public void DoSomeStuff(T input)
    {
        T result = m_handler(input);
        // some stuff
    }
}
```

Another way would be to move the string-specific behaviour into a separate class and simply make an instance of that class if you want specific behaviour tied to a specific type

```
public delegate T SomeHandler<T>(T input);

public class SomeClass<T>
{
    protected SomeHandler<T> m_handler;

    protected SomeClass()
    {

    }

    public SomeClass(SomeHandler<T> handler)
    {
        m_handler = handler;
    }

    public void DoSomeStuff(T input)
    {
        T result = m_handler(input);
        // some stuff
    }
}

public class SomeStringClass : SomeClass<string>
{
    public SomeStringClass()
    {
        m_handler = DefaultStringHandler;
    }

    private string DefaultStringHandler(string input)
    {
        // Do default string stuff here...
        return input;
    }

    public SomeStringClass(SomeHandler<string> handler):base(handler)
    {

    }
}
```